# StringBuilder encoding in Java

Tags: file, encoding, stringbuilder, fileinputstream

I have a method which loads file from sdcard (Android) and then reads it with StringBuilder. The text which im reading is written with my native language characters such as ą ś ć ź ż... 
StringBuilder (or FileInputStream) can't read them properly unfortunately. How I can set proper encoding ?

here is the code :

```
File file = new File(filePath);
            FileInputStream fis = null;
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                int content;
                while ((content = fis.read()) != -1) {
                    builder.append((char) content);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (fis != null)
                        fis.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("File Contents = " + builder.toString());
            contactService.updateContacts(builder.toString());
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

for example you could try an InputStreamReader combinded with a BufferedReader, that should do the trick:

```
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader((InputStream)fis, "UTF-8");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
String line;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
}
```

So long,
Tom

Comment: At line : 
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader, "UTF-8");
I get error that I should delete "UTF-8" to match BufferedReader constructor.

Comment: This is ok : BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((InputStream)fis, "UTF-8"));

Comment: Right! Sorry, I corrected it. The InputStreamReader is the one to set the encoding to!